# Form Fields extracted out of order, Pdfbox

Tags: java, forms, pdf, pdfbox

How to extract the form Field in the order in which they are present in the Pdf Fillable form.

```
PDAcroForm acroForm = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
List<PDField> fields = acroForm.getFields();
```

This fields list is not in order(as page hierarchy). Does Pdfbox maintain any order for the fields extraction. I need to extract the fields as per the flow of the page.

Comment: What do you mean by *as page hierarchy*?

Comment: what I mean from hierarchy is, from top to bottom of the pdf page. The order in which the fields are obtained seems to be random

Comment: You retrieved the fields of the document, not their visualizations on a specific page (fields can be invisible or have multiple occurrances on the same or on different pages). So why should they be sorted by order of appearance? *I need to extract the fields as per the flow of the page* - Then you should iterate the `PDAnnotation`s of the page, find the form field widgets there, and sort them by their `getRectangle`.

Comment: `acroForm.getFields()` will only get the root level fields. Read the javadoc.